# AXIS Network Camera not able to connect to a shared folder for storage on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, shared-folders, axis

Trying to set up a storage for my Axis Camera to a shared folder, but getting this error:

[image]

The folder is shared properly with full access to everyone, and I can access it no problem `\\MYPCNAME\Camera` in Chrome or file explorer.

**Please advise?**

Comment: Likely the same problem - https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/axis-network-camera-not-able-to-connect-to-smb-share.82713/ - so you may want to follow that thread and try the very last solution/workaround.

Comment: I am not using that FreeNAS software, just a default web interface of the camera's firmware

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: not working either, enabling netbios under network adapter or disabling it - still the same problem